# Rendering queryset on template without <QuerySet [<User:>]>

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-queryset, django-2.1

I am rendering a ManyToManyField in my template but it is shown like this :

```
<QuerySet [<User: Guido>]>
```

And I just want to print out the username without the function.

My **views.py**

```
class HotelListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
  model = Hotel

  def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(collaborateurs=self.request.user)
```

**My template**

```
{% for Hotel in object_list %}
     {{ Hotel.collaborateurs.ALL }}
          {% endfor %}
```

Thanks.

**Edit**

Models.py

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
collaborateurs = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Liste des collaborateurs autorisés")
code = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Code hôtel", null=True, blank=True)
email_manager = models.EmailField(max_length=150,verbose_name="Contact RH", null=True, blank=True)
contact_rh = models.EmailField(max_length=150,verbose_name="Contact RH", null=True, blank=True)
contact_gm = models.EmailField(max_length=150,verbose_name="Contact GM",null=True, blank=True)
payday = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Jour de paye prévu du mois", null=True, blank=True)
hotel = models.CharField(max_length=500,verbose_name="Nom de l'hôtel")
planning = models.URLField(max_length=500, verbose_name="Planning du mois", null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.hotel

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('hotel')
```

Comment: Does collaborateurs model have a \_\_repr\_\_?

Comment: Hi ! See my updated code. No it does not, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through the collaborators as well.

```
{% for Hotel in object_list %}
   {% for collaborator in Hotel.collaborateurs.all %}
      {{  collaborator.name }}
   {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

(Obviously replace `name` with the relevant field from the model.)

Comment: It does not work. I have still the queryset being shown like that : <QuerySet [<User: test>,>